# Chrome on Windows, Print Preview is dull, as well as prints

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, printing, color-profiles

I am printing from a windows 10.0.19042 Build 19042 and using Chrome and a sample image from Canon and a Canon TS6100 printer. When the print preview displays, the colors are dull, compared to the original image. When printing, it matches the dull preview. Everything is on the default settings, so not too sure what the issue is. A color profile, driver, not too sure. Can anyone help?

Chrome Preview
[image]

Windows Photo, Preview
[image]

Sample image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a no-fix situation, but to explain a bit why this is...

The 3rd image is profiled as ProPhoto RGB, the others you can't tell as they're screenshot & have no embedded profiles at all. Chrome might be attempting to soft-proof CMYK, hence the dull colours. The test for that is compare it to a print.
The Windows preview doesn't seem to know what to do with it. My guess is it will just throw the image at the printer as either a guesswork sRGB or even try to send ProPhoto & let the printer do what it can with it.
This *might* end up being a best guess, as the printer might make a better guess from ProPhoto than Windows or Chrome does. It will be marginal either way. The only way to find out is run prints from each & compare.

Neither your screen nor your printer will have a hope in h£ll of actually achieving ProPhoto colour gamut. Your printer uses CMYK, which cannot even achieve the brightness of standard sRGB, let alone the enormous gamut of ProPhoto. Your screen should manage sRGB, but again nowhere near ProPhoto.
In general, trying to show an image made with a "better" colour gamut than your screen can display will result in areas where the colour is totally saturated, 'all the guns are on full, nowhere else to go'.

Using my own fully calibrated setup which is capable of Adobe RGB - better than sRGB but not as good as ProPhoto - then soft-proofing to a generic CMYK I get this

[image]

So, this is already a double compensation - from a guesswork ProPhoto to generic CMYK on a screen that also cannot display ProPhoto, then saved as sRGB to post on here… which we're not really certain *your* screen can display properly ;)
This, however, is a rough approximation of what your printer *may* be able to achieve under optimum conditions.

In short…
even if the profiling was accurate on screen & printer, there's still no way you can see the correct original photo on screen & even less chance of being able to print it.